# Restricted View wont open the pdf

Tags: restricted-access

I have a document library with unique permissions. My goal is to restrict users from downloading PDF files and accessing other libraries and sites. To achieve this, I selected the "Restricted View" SharePoint Online out-of-the-box permission. However, users are now able to see the library, but they encounter an "Access Denied" error message every time they attempt to open a PDF file.

Can you please help me with this.

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you investigated if the permission level "View Only" will be sufficient for you? It will allow viewing more non-office file types